# Mongo Node Driver Inserts Integer Values Instead of Doubles

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm using the Mongo Native Javascript driver to insert data into a Mongo database. All of the docs I've read say that Mongo stores all of its numeric values as Doubles, and Javascript also stores all of its numerics as doubles. I can confirm that this works in the shell:

```
PRIMARY> db.products.insertOne({id: 10, price: 10})
PRIMARY> db.products.insertOne({id: 11, price: 11.99})

PRIMARY> db.products.aggregate([{$project: { price: {$type: "$price"}}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("605525ed8f87f3c9bc136a69"), "price" : "double" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("605525fb8f87f3c9bc136a6a"), "price" : "double" }
```

However, when I insert values from the Javascript driver, they are not all doubles, but instead the integer-looking number is stored with a bsontype of `int`:

```
-- Node
  await products.insertOne({id: 1, price: 20});
  await products.insertOne({id: 2, price: 20.85});

--Mongo Shell
PRIMARY> db.products.aggregate([{$project: { price: {$type: "$price"}}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6055261ee2efe2622736a36e"), "price" : "int" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6055261ee2efe2622736a36f"), "price" : "double" }
```

Is there a way in the mongo js driver to force it to always store numbers as doubles? I am ultimately reading this into a Java program which really wants the incoming types to be consistent, so if I can make them that way on insert I'd like to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can use https://plugins.mongoosejs.io/plugins/double

```
const Double = require('@mongoosejs/double');

const productsSchema = new Schema({ price: Double });

console.log(new Double(5));

Output - Double {
  path: 5,
  instance: 'Double',
  validators: [],
  getters: [],
  setters: [],
  options: SchemaTypeOptions {},
  _index: null,
  [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true }
```

You can check the source code here

https://github.com/mongoosejs/mongoose-double/blob/master/lib/index.js

---

**Option 2**

You can use  `mongoose.Decimal128`-

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-Decimal128

```
const productsSchema = new Schema({ price: mongoose.Decimal128 });

Insert query will be like this -"price":{"$numberDecimal":"5"}
```

> The Mongoose Decimal128 SchemaType. Used for declaring paths in your schema that should be 128-bit decimal floating points. Do not use this to create a new Decimal128 instance, use mongoose.Types.Decimal128 instead.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-854

---

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#numberint

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#numberdecimal

> The mongo shell treats all numbers as 64-bit floating-point double values by default. The mongo shell provides the NumberDecimal() constructor to explicitly specify 128-bit decimal-based floating-point values capable of emulating decimal rounding with exact precision. This functionality is intended for applications that handle monetary data, such as financial, tax, and scientific computations.

Mongo shell default insertion for the number is double to insert int we have to typecast using NumberInt

```
db.data.insertOne({ "numDouble":20.87,  "numInt": NumberInt(1) })
```

https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/622

---

Another option not sure it will work.

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/double.html

typecast the value to `Double` while inserting the value

```
const Double = require("mongodb").Double;

await products.insertOne({id: 1, price: Double(20) });
console.log(new Double(5))

Output - Double { _bsontype: 'Double', value: 5 }
```

> A class representation of the BSON Double type.
> class Double()

> Arguments:
> value (number) – the number we want to represent as a double.
> Returns:    double

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. Curious if you know why that's the case, though? Is it intended behavior by the js driver?

Comment: @jpavs I think that's the default behavior from the JS driver, I think it will be better to use https://plugins.mongoosejs.io/plugins/double or mongoose.Decimal128. As from shell, it inserts always double by default

Comment: FWIW the casting to double worked for me, thanks for the suggestion. I also received confirmation from Mongo that their driver is designed to do this. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-3164

Comment: @jpavs Awesome, which one  const Double = require('@mongoosejs/double') or const Double = require("mongodb").Double; ???

Comment: require(mongodb).double